# PHP serialize() format

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization

The problem is with storing serialized Data in Wordpress database.
What I'm trying to do:
I'm trying to store ID's of images as serialized array:

```
$image_id_array = array(0=>1234, 1=>2345, 2=>3456);
$gallery_serialized = serialize($image_id_array);
update_post_meta($post_id, 'gallery', $gallery_serialized);
```

Result I need to be stored looks like this:

```
a:3:{i:0;i:1234;i:1;i:2345;i:2;i:3456;}
```

Result, that is actually stored:

```
s:41:"a:20:{i:0;i:1234;i:1;i:2345;i:2;i:3456;}";
```

How can I drop **s:** value and columns?

Comment: Looks like you have multiple `serialize()` calls somewhere. The code you've provided gives what you want.

Comment: Do you try to skip your serialization? try: `update_post_meta($post_id, 'gallery', $image_id_array);`

Comment: You right, seems that update_post_meta serialize data by itself. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that `update_post_meta` serializing data by itself.
Solution:

```
update_post_meta($post_id, 'gallery', $image_id_array);
```

Thanks to @Neodan